# how to block only certain outgoing ip connection with iptables

Tags: centos, iptables

(Centos 5.5) to block xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:

```
# iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP -d xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

then verify by:

```
# iptables -L OUTPUT --line-numbers

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
2    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
3    DROP       all  --  anywhere             xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

It doesn't work; what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You have the `ACCEPT` from anywhere to anywhere first in the table, so that matches and your `DROP` rule is never reached.

Use `-I` instead of `-A` in this case to insert the rule at the head of the table.

Note that when writing scripts it's generally preferable to use `-A` as then the rules are added in the same order as they're listed in the script.

Comment: Additionally, **incoming** connections from the "blocked" IPs will still allow outgoing communication as they'll match the `NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED` rule.

Comment: thanks I'll remove the rule and try -I. I see, so the ACCEPT all rule should be always at the end when blacklisting ip/port

Comment: @cidfenmaria If blacklisting specific addresses but allowing all others, yes (or just have the `OUTPUT` policy set to `ACCEPT`). If blacklisting all but allowing specific addresses, the final rule would be `DROP` (or, again, use the policy, but **be careful if doing this over ssh**). Each rule is processed, in order, from top to bottom, until it jumps to a `DROP`, `REJECT` or `ACCEPT` action.

Comment: I've made changes and after a few days and run #netstat -n | grep <ip address I blocked>. the ip still exist?
tcp        0      1 <host ip>:44760       <blocked ip>:6667         SYN_SENT